# Adding animation to a button inside a collectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have created a class called ButtonJitter.

```
class ButtonJitter: UIButton
{

    func jitter()
    {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = 0.05
        animation.repeatCount = 6
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.init(x: self.center.x - 7.0, y: self.center.y))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.init(x: self.center.x, y: self.center.y))
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
    }

    func jitterLong()
    {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = 0.05
        animation.repeatCount = 10
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.init(x: self.center.x - 10.0, y: self.center.y))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.init(x: self.center.x, y: self.center.y))
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
    }

}
```

Now I want to call one of these functions when user taps to a button inside a collectionview cell. I have set the class of the button as ButtonJitter as well. Also I have created an action for that button. But I can't call any of these functions inside of that action.

```
@IBAction func soundBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundArrayPets[sender.tag], withExtension: "mp3")
        {
            player.removeAllItems()
            player.insert(AVPlayerItem(url: url), after: nil)
            player.play()
        }
    }
```

So my question is how can I access my animation functions so when user taps the button inside my collection view it animates? Or should I call them inside my cellForItem atIndexPath method? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd simply use a guard let statement to check if my sender is of class ButttonJitter, and have the compiler consider it as such. Like this:

```
@IBAction func soundBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let jitterButton = sender as? ButtonJitter else {
        return
    }
    // Now, if the sender is a button of class ButtonJitter, you have a button that is of that class: jitterButton. Do whatever you want with it. Like call jitterButton.jitter()
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundArrayPets[sender.tag], withExtension: "mp3")
    {
        player.removeAllItems()
        player.insert(AVPlayerItem(url: url), after: nil)
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That worked but i have no idea what you did here :)

Comment: @Volkan In your original function, your button is considered as being UIButton, even if it is a ButtonJitter. And UIButton doesn't have the jitter functions. But if you safely (hence the guard let) cast it to your ButtonJitter class, than you have your jittering back :-)